# How to get a newly copied Item ID in OneDrive SDK?

Tags: c#, onedrive

Below is the code I use to copy an item from folder A to B. It is going good.

```
var client = GetOneDriveClient();
var response = await client.Drive.Items["FILE_ID"].Copy("NEW_FILE_NAME", new ItemReference { Id = "COPY_TO_FOLDER_ID" }).Request().PostAsync();

//below line throws an error
var item = response.PollForOperationCompletionAsync(null, CancellationToken.None);
```

I am able to see the `monitorUrl` from the `response` variable and the file was successfully copied which I can to know through the monitor URL.

I would like to know at least how to read the monitor URL since it is a private variable.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Graph API code I'm using now which works 100% successfully.

I am now able to get the monitor URL and item ID from the monitor URL. I am posting my code for people who may need it in the future.

```
var client = new RestClient(ONEDRIVE_ENDPOINT + $"/drives/{driveID}/items/{fileID}/copy");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessToken());
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
var body = new { parentReference = new { id = copyToFolderID }, name = newFileName };
request.AddJsonBody(body);

var response = client.Execute(request);
var monitorURI = new Uri(response.Headers.Where(x => x.Name == "Location").First().Value.ToProperString());
var newFileID = monitorURI.Segments.Last();
```